# dtypeをobjectからint64に変更する方法を教えてください

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_maize = pd.read_csv("PSD online data maize.csv")
print(df_maize["Name"])
print(df_maize["Production"])
print(df_maize["Exports"])
```

#プリントした結果を見ると4桁以下のデータがint64で5桁以上のデータがobjectになっています#
0    2013
1    2014
2    2015
3    2016
4    2017
5    2018
6    2019
7    2020
8    2021
9    2022
Name: Name, dtype: int64
0    248,453
1    249,764
2    264,992
3    263,613
4    259,071
5    257,174
6    260,779
7    260,670
8    272,552
9    277,200
Name: Production, dtype: object
0    22
1    13
2     4
3    61
4    19
5    19
6    12
7     4
8     3
9    20
Name: Exports, dtype: int64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`,`を取り除きます．

```py
...
>>> df_maize.loc[:, "Production"].str.replace(",", "").astype("int64")
0    248453
1    249764
2    264992
3    263613
4    259071
5    257174
6    260779
7    260670
8    272552
9    277200
Name: Production, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

使っているCSVデータファイルの内容を提示すると助言・回答が出やすいでしょう。
関連する列だけを抽出すれば、おそらくこんなデータになっているのでは？

```
Name,Production,Exports
2013,"248,453",22
2014,"249,764",13
2015,"264,992",4
2016,"263,613",61
2017,"259,071",19
2018,"257,174",19
2019,"260,779",12
2020,"260,670",4
2021,"272,552",3
2022,"277,200",20
```

[pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)のパラメータに`thousands`というのがあり、それを指定すれば読み込み時に対処してくれるでしょう。

> thousands : str, optional
> Thousands separator.

[【pandas】read_csvの使い方まとめ](https://www.self-study-blog.com/dokugaku/python-pandas-dataframe-read_csv/)

> 数値・文字列を指定・変更する方法
> 引数　　　 デフォルト値　意味
> thousands　None　　　　 桁区切り文字を指定できる。例えば','など。

ということで、こちらの行を：

```
df_maize = pd.read_csv("PSD online data maize.csv")
```

こちらにすれば良いのでは？

```
df_maize = pd.read_csv("PSD online data maize.csv", thousands=',')
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。試してみます。